# How do I replace a variable with another variable. ruamel.yaml

Tags: python, dictionary

I do not know how to ask this question correctly.
I have a code like this

```
import sys
from ruamel.yaml import YAML

Human = "Alex"
AgeNumber = 24
TypeName = "B"
d = dict(Human=dict(Age=AgeNumber,Type=TypeName))
yaml = YAML()
yaml.dump(d, sys.stdout)
```

And i get

```
Human:
  Age: 24
  Type: B
```

Everything is correct here except for the variable Human.
Human variable is not replaced by alex.
My knowledge is lacking what is the essence of the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has little to do with `ruamel.yaml`, but all with how you define a dict.

If you use the `dict(key1=val1, key2=val2)` syntax as you do the `key[12]` in there are taken literally as strings. What you should do in this case is:

```
d = {Human: dict(Age=AgeNumber,Type=TypeName)}
```

and then dump